# Поиск одинаковых элементов в двух списках

Tags: python

```
def func(l1, l2):
    for x in l1:
        for y in l2:
            if x == y:
                return True
            return False

print(func([1,2,3,4,5], [5,6,7,8,9])) >> False
print(func([1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9]))   >> False
```

Почему функция не видит элемент 5 в первом случае?

Если попробовать вот так:

```
def func(l1, l2):
    for x in l1:
        for y in l2:
            if x == y:
                return True
                return False

print(func([1,2,3,4,5], [5,6,7,8,9])) >> True
print(func([1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9])) >> None
```

Теперь видит 5ку в первом случае, но почему выдает None во втором? Как сделать, чтобы выдавал False?

Comment: Я там поправил табуляции, проверьте - так ли у вас изначально было. Табуляции в Python очень важны, они определяют логику работы программы зачастую.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что во втором случае `False` недостижимо. А в первом случае `return False` будет исполнено после сравнения первого элемента со всеми элементами второго.

Проще будет сделать так:

```
def func(l1, l2):
    for x in l1:
        if x in l2:
            return True
    return False

print(func([1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9])) # False
print(func([1,2,3,4,5], [5,6,7,8,9])) # True
```

Comment: Я там поправил табуляции в вопросе, но какие были исходно - сложно угадать. Как сейчас там вообще после первого же сравнения выход из функции по-любому )

Comment: да у меня и еще более простой вариант есть: def func(l,l1):
    return any(l) in l1
l = [1,2,3]
l1 = [1,2,3]
func(l,l1) Вот только приведенный выше код все еще не понятен

Comment: а почему во втором случае return False не исполняется после сравнения первого элемента со всеми элементами второго?